# Intel Vtune weird behavior for fortran code on linux

Tags: fortran, intel-vtune

I have compiled the fortran program with different optimization flags. I have one program with default optimization flag -O2 and another compiled program with -fast optimization flag. I was able to open the program compiled with optimization flag -O2. So, when we try to load the program in Vtune, the program also executes ?

However, when I try to load the program compiled with the optimization flag -fast, Vtune throws an error "Failed to finalize the result". The result you are opening is empty. This may be caused by an error during the data collection. What does this actually mean ? I went throught other threads in this forum , but couldn't quite understand what it means.

The collector Messages I got are as follows:

Error: Binary file of the analysis target does not contain symbols required for profiling. See documentation for more details.
Error: Valid dlopen symbol is not found in the static binary of the analysis target.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 system.

Thanks so much. Please reply soon.

Jdbaba

Comment: Have you asked this question on the Intel developer forum ?  Or even asked their tech support ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what compiler you're using (a few have `-fast`), but my best guess from what you're describing is that `-fast` strips the binary so there are no debug symbols. With `gcc` or `icc` (and presumably `gfortran` or `ifort`) you should compile with `-g`, but I'm not sure what the equivalent in your Fortran compiler might be.